# reading from a closed inputstream in itext

Tags: java, itext

is it possible create a `PdfReader` that reads a closed `InputStream`.or i have to create a new `InputStream` and copy the contents of the current `InputStream`.Copying InputStreams is not direct and takes time and lot of memory for large `pdf` files. Any other alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of opening up of an already closed stream.

You can use a `PushbackInputStream` if you want to read again and again.
Unless closed, it allows you to seek a position in the stream you wish and from there you can read forward again.

**Refer to**: [***java.io.PushbackInputStream***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is your InputStream already closed or 'just' already consumed? If that's the case you can try to [reset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) the stream when that is [supported](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29) by the InputStream type you are using.